# Bot gets and replies to a mention on twitter problem

Tags: python, api, twitter

I'm trying to create a Twitter bot with Python. So my problem is, is there a function that allows me to get the mentions of a tweet, so I can reply to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write a bot who can reply to tweets mentionning it :

You can use the standard [statuses/filter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/filter-realtime/api-reference/post-statuses-filter) API to watch for tweets mentionning your bot.

For this, the [standard search operators](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/rules-and-filtering/overview/standard-operators) says that you just have to write "@yourbot" in the query to get tweets mentionning this user.

Then you can use the [POST statuses/update](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update) to reply, with the `in_reply_to_status_id` parameter which is the tweet id to reply to.

Comment: And here's the [rate limit](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/rate-limits) that must needs to be considered before/while developing that bot.